# Netflix on Firefox/Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: firefox, netflix

I am perfectly capable of watching Netflix on Google Chrome, since it's supported, but, I would like to know if it's possible to use Firefox to watch Netflix since I prefer this web browser over Chrome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Enable: Preferences > Contents > Play DRM Content;
2. Download the User Agent Switcher Add-On. After installed change your User Agent to Chrome Browser and Linux System. Netflix will think you are using Google Chrome.

User Agent Switcher Add-On: [https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher-firefox/]

Comment: Not working on Ubuntu 16.04 and Firefox 55....